# How do I set the variables in this javascript file to match variables from Flask/Python?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I have a Javascript file that enables drop down menus dynamic (i.e. a selection from one drop down impacts the others). I would like to use this file in conjunction with multiple forms but I have hard-coded the starting variables in this file to html elements 'inverter_oem' and 'inverter_model_name'.

In other forms, I will need to reference different objects.

How can I accomplish this?
I would like to create the variables in Javascript this way:

```
const selecting_dropdown_menu = document.getElementById(variable1_from_flask);
const filtered_dropdown_menu = document.getElementById(variable2_from_flask);
```

My current approach is to try and pass variables from the Flask route using render_template. (I have also tried other stack overflow solutions but no luck)

```
@db_queries.route('/db_query_dynamic_form/<form_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def db_query_dynamic_form(form_name):
    # use methods to get form and endpoint for outside loop

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # inside loop when form complete
        return render_template('list.html', result=query_results["filtered_tables"], columns=query_results["column_names"])

    # added variable to pass to jinja template
    return render_template(form_endpoint["endpoint"], form=form_endpoint["form"], var="value1")
```

The jinja template form is as follows

```
% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Inverter Dynamic  Search{% endblock %}
{% block heading %}Inverter Dynamic Search{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

  <form method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag()}}
    {{ form.inverter_oem.label }}{{ form.inverter_oem }}<br>
    {{ form.inverter_model_name.label }}{{ form.inverter_model_name }}<br>
    {{form.submit()}}

    {{test}}
  </form>
    <script>
      myVar = {{ var }}
    </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='search_inverter_dynamic.js') }}"></script>


{% endblock %}
```

However, I dont get a value in the javascript file when I try

```
console.log(myVar);
```

Here is the original JScode with the "hardcoded" variables

```
//acquire inverter_oem value from form
const inverter_oem_select = document.getElementById('inverter_oem');
const inverter_model_name_select = document.getElementById('inverter_model_name');

//add event listener to capture selected oem in dropdown
inverter_oem_select.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let oem = '../modelNameByOEM//' +  e.target.value;
    console.log(oem);
    getIt(oem);
});

//recover a JSON containing the list of models from a specific oem
async function getIt(input) {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(input);
        console.log(res.data);
        optionHTML = '';
        for (let modelName of res.data.modelNameOem) {
            //console.log(res.modelName.name);
            optionHTML += '<option value="' + modelName.name + '">' + modelName.name + '</option>';
            //console.log(optionHTML);
        }
        inverter_model_name_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Could not reach endpoint modelNameByOEM')
        console.log(err);
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you include more of your JS code including how selected elements are used? Instead of selecting by ID, can you use a CSS class instead?

Comment: Sure, I'll add the whole original file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja does not know that you want to pass a variable inside a JavaScript environment, so it cannot add the quotation marks automatically around a string variable. It just replaces `{{ var }}` with `value1` causing a syntax error. Just add the quotation marks and then you can access `myVar` inside the JS environment:

```
<script>
myVar = "{{ var }}"
</script>
```

Note: if you want to pass a more complex data structure and/or user submitted values, you should look at the [`tojson` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson) that safely renders the data.

Comment: It works Dauros, thank you!  I was looking up the reason the quotation marks allow the variable to be passed in the Jinja documentation but cannot find an explanation.

Could you elaborate why this works?  Does Jinja pass that variable as a string with quotation marks and then JS code reads "{{ var }}" as a variable?

Comment: During the rendering Jinja looks for Jinja-specific statements/expressions, like `{{ var }}` or `{% if some_other_var %}` and evaluates them. The so-called mustache syntax: `{{ var }}` tells Jinja that it should look for a Python variable called `var` and replace the whole `{{ var }}` term in the template with the value of `var`. But in your template you have to make sure that the replaced value will be placed in the right environment. In your case: the `var` is a string, therefore you have to put quotation marks around it at the declaration. Jinja don't know anything outside its own context.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks a ton